# AppsFlyer Android Integration

Tags: android, tracking, appsflyer

Link step to integration AppsFlyer to Project Android: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android

After following your step, everything go well on debug build but i have crash when build release, my project configured with proguard

```
-dontwarn com.appsflyer.**  
-dontwarn com.android.installreferrer  
-keep public class com.android.installreferrer.** { *; }
```

I found issue in `onInstallReferrerSetupFinished method && mReferrerClient.getInstallReferrer();`

I don't know i'm wrong proguard config or Appsflyer sdk have problem with connect .AIDL 
These're logs from Fabric crash

> Binder invocation to an incorrect interface 
>   android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1599) 
>   com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClientImpl.getInstallReferrer (Unknown Source) 
>   com.appsflyer.o.onInstallReferrerSetupFinished (Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you add install referrer to your gradle: `'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'`?

Comment: Also please post full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation: 
[support.appsflyer.com](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android#23-adding-the-sdk-to-your-project)

In your proguard-rules file put:

```
-dontwarn com.android.installreferrer
```

In your Gradle file

```
implementation 'com.appsflyer:segment-android-integration:+'
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
```

In my case I am using appsflyer with segment so my code is:

```
Analytics analytics = new Analytics.Builder(context, BuildConfig.SEGMENT_KEY)
            .trackApplicationLifecycleEvents()
            .flushQueueSize(AnalyticsConstants.CONFIG.SEGMENT_QUEUE_SIZE)
            .use(AppsflyerIntegration.FACTORY)
            .build();
```

I hope this help you!